# JavaScript Regex - Negation of (?:)

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi let's say I have this string:

```
var text = "Jackie Chan | Jack Frost | Capt.Jack Sparrow"
```

I want to find every `/Jack/` except Jack Frost.

I can easily do this by using `?!`, but it doesn't include the last name

```
text.match(/[^\s]*Jack[^\s]*(?!\sFrost)/g);
// Result: ['Jackie', 'Capt.Jack']

// I want the result to be ['Jackie Chan', 'Capt.Jack Sparrow']
```

So I basically need the negation of `?:`. Is there such thing?

I don't want to do `(?:Chan|Sparrow)` because if I add another Jack, it won't get matched.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go on with matching after the lookeahead:

```
text.match(/\S*Jack\S*(?!\s+Frost)\s+\S+/g)
```

Comment: Hi thanks it works. Can you elaborate more about the last part `(?!\s+Frost)\s+\S+` ? Is the group `()` ignored when not found?

Comment: Yes, lookeaheads are "zero-width", they don't capture anything.